# Number Theory: Remainders

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

“ Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $0<a<b$.

Given $b=qa+r$ where $0\leq r<a$.

Prove that $r$ is always less than $\frac{b}{2}$. ”

I have played around with several examples and have realized that this should always be the case. But how do I go about proving this? Thank you.

p.s. Apologies for the confusion. $q, r$ are all integers!

Comment: What is $q$? Is it $q\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar p.s. Apologies for the confusion. q,r are all integers!

Comment: I was misreading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$q\geq1$, because $b>a$, so $b=qa+r\geq a+r>r+r.$

Comment: A more succinct proof. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $r\geq b/2$, then multiply the whole thing by $2$:
$$
2b=2qa+2r=2qa+(b+c)
$$
where $c=2r-b\geq 0$. Therefore we have $b=2qa+c=qa+r$, so we have $qa+c=r$. Since $b>a$, we know that $q\geq 1$, so this implies that $r\geq a$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much Ian. I've stuck on this problem for almost forty minutes when knowing this must be true but not finding a way of proving it. Using the fact that $b>a$ to conclude $q\geq 1$ and hence $r\geq a$ really helps. Thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem! The solution below is also good.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ b = qa\!+\!r > 2r \iff qa > r$